# Django: No Topic matches the given query

Tags: python, django-views, custom-error-pages

**Page not found (404)**
No Topic matches the given query.
Request Method:   GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/boards/1/topics/9/
Raised by:    boards.views.topic_posts
Using the URLconf defined in discussion_board.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. admin/ [name='home'] boards/int:board_id/ [name='board_topics']
   boards/int:board_id/new [name='new_topic']
   boards/int:board_id/topics/int:topic_id/ [name='topic_posts']

---

The current path, boards/1/topics/9/, matched the last one.`

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

-

### List item

Comment: Question not clear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to creat a url which is

Comment: sorrry wait : path('boards/<int:board_id>/topics/<int:topic_id>/',
         views.topic_posts, name='topic_posts'),

Comment: but it give me page not found 404

Comment: this the view   def topic_posts(request, board_id, topic_id):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, board__pk=board_id, pk=topic_id)
    # get_object_or_404(Topic, board__id=board_id, pk=topic_pk)

    return render(request, 'topic_post.htmll', {'topic': topic})

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.